# Forward all emails sent to AWS subdomain to one single account

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, dns, amazon-route53, mail-server

I have many email addresses, one for each user, on a subdomain like so: `username@upload.mywebsite.com`

I'd like to receive all of these emails into one Inbox for me to use, e.g. `combineduploads@mywebsite.com`

I'm using AWS Workmail and Route 53. I'm not sure where to start. Maybe this can be done with DNS records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using AWS SES and AWS Lambda where you can setup a SES rule to trigger a Lambda function to forward the mails received to a predefined email address.

For more details refer [Forwarding Emails to your Inbox Using Amazon SES](https://medium.com/@ashan.fernando/forwarding-emails-to-your-inbox-using-amazon-ses-2d261d60e417). You can launch the CloudFormation stack to automate the majority of the configurations.

Comment: Wow awesome - that post and CloudFormation looks great, and I've launched it successfully. But I'm still not receiving emails sent to arbitrary addresses `example-1258@upload.mywebsite.com`. When I send an email to these addresses, I get a Delivery Failure notification (the SMTP server rejected the address). And no sign of activity from SES or SNS. Any ideas why the SMTP server is rejecting the address?

Comment: Hi @ben. Have taken SES out of sandbox mode or whitelist example-1258@upload.mywebsite.com email by sending and accepting email received?

Comment: Didn't have the right MX record set... will see if I can get it working